# Which statistical analysis test to perform to find the difference in connectivity between regions of Default Mode Network?

Tags: brain, statistics, test, connectionism, group

I have three groups each with 30 participants. I have 30 binary adjacency/connectivity matrix for each group which represents the connectivity between regions of Default Mode Network . I want to find the difference in the connectivity of these regions between these three group. Please recommend which statistical analysis test should i perform? Also if links to thte related material can be provided I will be greatly thankful. Looking forward for some help.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a more focused research question than "find the difference in the connectivity". What's your specific hypothesis?

Comment: I am trying to find how the regions in default mode network differed in connectivity before and after the treatment.

Comment: You need to decide what you mean by that. Do you mean average connectivity within the entire DMN? Do you mean connections between each node of the DMN to other nodes in the brain? What is your research question and specific hypothesis?

Comment: connections between each node of the DMN to other nodes in the brain

Comment: Okay, you still **really** need to narrow down what that hypothesis is. Are you looking for averages across the DMN? Differences in difference for nodes in DMN? How many separate hypotheses are you testing? You have only N=30 per group, so unless the differences are absolutely massive, you're probably barely powered to detect a single difference, let alone after correcting for multiple comparisons across all the possible differences you might attempt to measure.

Comment: Basically I want to find if there's a difference on connectivity between regions before and after the treatment. For example if before treatment node 1 and node 2 are connected positively i.e. 1 and after treatment it becomes -1 or zero. Which test can be applied?

Comment: That's still not a specific question, and is not a typical or meaningful way to phrase such a question in neuroscience. Until you have a specific question to answer, it is not possible to design a statistical test to answer it. It's possible you intend to test many different statistical questions at once, in which case you still need to be able to describe what all of those different statistical questions are.